# AG-Grid : Share same custom editor between multiple columns

Tags: ag-grid

I have grid implemented using `ag-grid`. And I have created custom `cell-editor` for a particular column which is `bootstrap-select` as mentioned below:

```
self.selectCellEditor = function () { };
self.selectCellEditor.prototype = {
    init: function (params) {

      var options = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < params.values.length; i++) {
        options += '<li><a href="#" class="option">'+params.values[i]+'</a></li>';
      }

      this.inputSelect = document.createElement('div');
      this.inputSelect.className = "dropdown btn-group bootstrap-select";
      this.inputSelect.innerHTML = '<button class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="btn-text">'+params.value+'</span>' +
          '<span class="caret"></span></button>' +
          '<ul class="dropdown-menu inner">'+options+'</ul>';

      return this.inputSelect;
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return $($(this.inputSelect).find('a')[1]).text();
    },
    getGui: function () {
        return this.inputSelect;
    },
    destroy: function () {
        $(this.inputSelect).remove();
    }
}
```

I want the same editor to be used by another column as well. But when I change the value of one column, it changes the value of other column also.

Here is the [Plnkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CvftI4FLxDw2wbyy15QG?p=preview)

In Demo, I have implemented custom cell editor for Country and Year columns.

Is there any feasible solution for this ?